# How to twist an object with Sverchok?

Tags: node-editor, sverchok

If I want to twist an object in Blender I can easily do it, for example with proportional editing:

[image]

How can I achieve the same result with Sverchok? I've been trying with "List item" but could not get results. I would like to twist an object imported from the scene with Object In rather than a mesh created directly with Sverchok.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way to do it. currently:

[image]

- first split the verts of the object
- then multiply each vert's vector by a unique matrix (which is some function of z-height here i'm multiplying the vertex's Z component by 51.94)
- then recombine using mesh_join.

We don't have a proportional editing method inside sverchok, you'd need to combine math nodes to emulate that feature. Not impossible, this layout should suggest further development.

You can import this json Gist ID directly [8e11420e351e79be0760f86c2f51de06](https://gist.github.com/zeffii/8e11420e351e79be0760f86c2f51de06) in the Sv Import/Export panel. (make sure you update Sverchok to `0.5.6.2` or later)

Answer (score 3):

why not use simple deformation node?
it is new node, that can twist, bend[image]